# I stopped an external hard drive in the middle of it setting sharing permissions. Now I can access some of the folders, but not others

Tags: windows-7, windows

I think the system set the sharing on about 25% of thousands of folders.  I've tried removing the share and readding, but nothing works.

any way to reset them so I can redo the permissions?

I'm using windows 7 home premium

Answer (score 1):

You can use [icacls](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_examples) to reset the file/folder permissions via command line.

So if you want to reset all the permissions for file/folders for `C:\Test` then execute the following set of commands in with elevated privileges ( with administrative rights)

```
CD C:\
CD Test
icacls * /T /Q /C /RESET
```

This would be easier than doing it via GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I will bet you will end up using [takeown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

```
takeown [/s <Computer> [/u [<Domain>\]<User name> [/p [<Password>]]]] /f <File name> [/a] [/r [/d {Y|N}]]
```

which will allow you to become owner of multiple files by descending to subdirectories. 
You will be able to access all of them but the ntfs permissions will still need to be fixed.
After you become owner just repeat the process of adding the permissions.